# Offers tab on mesos dashboard

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

What does offers tab on mesos-master dashboard represent? I have slaves registered to my master and has applications running on them deployed by marathon, but Offers tab shows nothing in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows offers presented to framework but not accepted yet. That's why page state `outstanding offers` in subtitle. Once offer is accepted it is no longer an offer and gets removed, so your offers tab is empty.

[Source](http://search-hadoop.com/m/0Vlr6vScS5DPmxp&subj=Re+mesos+0+24+1+and+0+25+0+offers+web+ui+not+appearing+to+work)